# It is possible to handle the task shut down from inside the Airflow Task?

Tags: neo4j, airflow, mwaa

We use Neo4j and call its queries from Airflow tasks. The issue is that these queries often don't stop when the task is marked as "Failed" or "Completed" in the Airflow GUI. So, I would like to find out a way how to call a kill query from inside the currently running task when the task is marked as "Failed" or "Completed".

In the Airflow, the query is executed using **session.run(query)** method from *GraphDatabase.driver*. Where *GraphDatabase* is a part of neo4j python library

Is it any straightforward solution how to do it?

Comment: Can you define your work as transaction functions and add timeout for your queries? @unit_of_work(timeout=100)

Comment: Docs here: https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/4.3/api.html#managed-transactions-ref

Comment: It may solve some part of the problem if I add limit to the matching part in the iterator to reduce the computation time. Then, using airflow schedule, the query would be just called again.

Answer (score 2):

Base Operator has "on_kill" method that you can override: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.on_kill

It's likely that the operator you use (Neo4j)  does not have it properly implemented - but you can always create a custom operator with proper on_kill implementation and possibly contribute it back as PR

Answer (score 0):

If you know the query id, you could try running the following query,

```
CALL dbms.killQuery(queryId)
```

See https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/query-management/ . This link also show you how to list running queries or transactions

Comment: Is it possible to know the query id while calling queries from neo4j python library?

Comment: not that i know of. I couldn't find any docs on that. Best I can think of is to use 'call dbms.listQueries()' and narrow down the query you are interested in and use that queryId

Comment: Is there a way to make the API call as blocking?

Comment: @floating_hammer what do you mean exactly by API call in this case?